# Pick some combinations of r elements out of all possible combinations of elements from an array of length n

Tags: python, memory, random, combinations

So I have a list of lists, say `superlist = [sublist1, sublist2, ...,sublistn]` of length n.

I need to randomly pick a large number of combinations of r elements from it, but not necessarily all of them. In my case, n=35, r=8, and the number of combinations needed are 10000.

The problem I am facing while running this on Python 3.9 is that the number of combinations goes to the order of 1e7, and as I am dealing with long lists within each combination, random shuffle is slow and takes up too much memory.
So my question is: is there a faster and less memory-intensive way to get a random set of combinations of the format nCr? Ideally, I would want to avoid generating all combinations as well.

What I tried was the following:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations as comb
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
largenumber = 10000
all_combs = np.array(list(comb(superlist, r)))
perm = np.arange(all_combs.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(perm)
if max(perm)<=largenumber:
   required_combs = all_combs[perm]
else:
   required_combs = all_combs[perm][0:largenumber]
```

The np.random.shuffle and the comb(superlist,r) become extremely slow and consume large amounts of memory. As I was running it on a cluster, the cluster was killing the process due to high memory usage.

Comment: What are elements in sublists? Are sublists of the same size?

Comment: To be clear you want r random numbers from n lists?

Comment: Why not randomly pick elements from each list, and then check if you already have that combination? 10k combinations should fit in memory just *fine*. This would become problematic if the number of *possible* combinations is low, but currently no such issue exists..

Comment: The elements in sublists are floats, and yes, sorry the sublists are of the same size.
I want 10,000 random combinations of r sublists from a list containing n sublists. Coming to Maarten's comment, the issue is that I want to pick combinations of r sublists. That is, a random pick of sublist1, sublist2 and sublist2, sublist1 should count as 1 pick (when r=2). This can be introduced as a condition, but I would expect that to increase the time taken to run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html, you'll find the last recipe is for `nth_combination`.  This is precisely what you need

So you can do:

```
combinations = math.comb(len(superlist), r)
indices = random(range(combinations), n)
result = [nth_combination(superlist, r, index) for index in indices]
```

Comment: Perfect, this works for me! I did not know about the `more_itertools` package which has the `nth_combination` recipe. Using that after using `random.sample()` to get the indices does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you liked my first answer.  Just for completeness, there is a completely different method of solving this similar to your original approach, but it uses a lot less space.

There is an old interview problem.  You have a conveyor belt with `count` widgets coming over it.  You need to pick `n` `(< count)` random widgets off the conveyor belt, but you only have one chance--when the item passes you on the conveyor belt--to pick the item.

The secret is to keep track of how many widgets there are remaining, and how many of those you still need to pick.  As an item goes by, you pick it with probability remaining_n / remaining_count.

```
def picker(iterator, count, n):
    for remaining_count in range(n, 0, -1):
        value = next(iterator)
        if random.random() <= (n / remaining_count):
            n -= 1
            yield value
            # optimization: return if n == 0.
```

So going back to your original code:

```
count = math.comb(len(superlist), r)
result = list(picker(comb(superlist, r), count, n)
# And if you need them to be in a random order:
random.shuffle(result)
```